# Why am I not getting any results with print and for?

Tags: python

I ran this code and for some reason am just getting blank output. Thought it was because it had looped through it already and I just missed it, and there isn't anything left to print but this happens even for a new file. Super new to Python so any help would be appreciated! Unrelated, is there a way to remove the >> lines in Visual Studio so I can see the output more clearly?

```
>>>buffet = ('rice','salad','beets','oranges','cake')
>>>
>>>print(buffet)
>>>
>>>#menu rewritten
>>>
>>>buffet = ('rice','salad','beets','ice cream','fudge')
>>>
>>>print("\nModified dimensions:")
>>>
>>>for buffetitem in buffet:
    print(buffetitem)
```

My output:

```
>>> buffet = ('rice','salad','beets','oranges','cake')
>>> 
>>> print(buffet)
('rice', 'salad', 'beets', 'oranges', 'cake')
>>> #menu rewritten
>>> 
>>> buffet = ('rice','salad','beets','ice cream','fudge')
>>> print("\nModified dimensions:")

Modified dimensions:
>>> 
>>> for buffetitem in buffet:
...     print(buffetitem)
...
```

Comment: When you type a multiline statement in the REPL, keep pressing enter until the 3 periods disappear if you want to execute the statements.

Comment: I hit enter in the terminal and the output showed but haven't always had to do this to show the print output. I feel silly now! Thanks :D Noted re: running multiline statements.

Comment: @user2781658 Multiple questions in multiple threads :-) No problem here though, but just so that some of the stricter ones do not flag your question or anything

Answer (score 1):

You should press enter until you see the `>>>` and then enter again. Then it should run.